# Counting non duplicates between 2 columns

Tags: mysql, select

Suppose we have two columns: Start & End.
Both columns store an integer id.

For each id in the Start column, I want to be able to determine whether the same id exists in the End column. If not, the count should increment by 1.

How can this be done?

Comment: Show us an example with a few rows and the expected result.

Comment: "in the end column" -- Do you mean:  "the end column of the same row"?  "the end column of _some_ row"?  And, what if the same Start shows up in multiple rows?  Ditto for End?  _The question is ambiguous; sample data would help._

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.Start) 
FROM TableName a
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableName b ON a.Start = b.End
WHERE b.Start IS NULL
```

Comment: Or `COUNT(DISTINCT a.Start)` in case there may be duplicates and you want to count unique entries only.

Comment: I like it Andriy, I will update the answer!

Comment: I didn't mean to imply your own suggestion was incorrect in any way, though. We don't know the details and the OP may well be after counting all entries, duplicates or not. Or maybe the columns can't have duplicates, in which case `COUNT(*)` would work for OP just as well. By suggesting the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` option, I merely meant to complement your answer rather than replace any part of it. But feel free to use my information as you see fit, of course – after all, it's your post. :)

Comment: No problems, but re-reading the question the OP specifically asked for "For each id in the Start column...", not "For each row in the Start column...", which is why I changed my answer. If they wanted a count of rows, COUNT(*) would have been appropriate, but they specifically asked for an ID count.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select Start, count(*)
From TBL
Where Start = End
Group by Start
```

Adding at the end

```
Having count(*) > 1
```

You'll see only rows with a match between your two columns.

If you want to check into a data set modify as follows:

```
Select Start
    From TBL
    Where Start in (
Select Distinct End From TBL)
```

With this one, you get only the Start value that you can find in End column.

Checking how many times this occurs:

```
Select Start, count(*)
        From TBL
        Where Start in (
    Select Distinct End From TBL)
    Group by Start
```

Comment: Ahhh but won't this only check whether it exists in the same row? I want to know whether each id n Start exists ANYWHERE in the End column. Thanks :)

Comment: Aaaahhhhh now I got it 

Comment: See answer updated

Comment: @MartinRand: Please update your question to make that point clear. Whoever else might want to take a go at your question shouldn't rely on important details left in comments under someone's answer.

Comment: @AndriyM Absolutely, of course! I'll make an edit, with what I've learned from the answer tomorrow when I've sobered up.